# Spring Boot logback over slf4j Debug mode

Tags: spring, spring-boot, slf4j, logback

I have a weird issue with logback in a spring boot application.

I have a simple config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration debug="true" scan="true" scanPeriod="30 seconds">
  <!--include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml"/-->
  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>
  <logger name="com.mypackage" level="debug"/>
  <root level="debug">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
  </root>
</configuration>
```

I start up using the `-Dlogging.configurationFile=..` correct path

The application picks up the file and gives the following output:

```
16:34:58,174 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - Setting ReconfigureOnChangeFilter scanning period to 30 seconds
16:34:58,212 |-INFO in ReconfigureOnChangeFilter{invocationCounter=0} - Will scan for changes in [[/home/..../logback.xml]] every 30 seconds.
16:34:58,212 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - Adding ReconfigureOnChangeFilter as a turbo filter
16:34:58,238 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender]
16:34:58,250 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [STDOUT]
16:34:58,384 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
16:34:58,615 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [com.myPackage] to DEBUG
16:34:58,615 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.RootLoggerAction - Setting level of ROOT logger to DEBUG
16:34:58,615 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [STDOUT] to Logger[ROOT]
16:34:58,618 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - End of configuration.
16:34:58,622 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator@447ecd43 - Registering current configuration as safe fallback point
```

The `pom.xml` is as follows:

```
 <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
 </dependency>
```

apart from *jcl* over *slf4j* and *slf4* .. 
also, I have excluded `commons-logging` from spring context.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What did you expect? the `debug="true"` is for showing startup information on logback, it isn't for enabling debug logging in general. Also judging from that your file isn't used but the default one from Spring Boot is being used. Make sure that your logback.xml file is in the correct location.

Comment: M. Deinum: I edited the logs in my original post. It seems the specified file is being scanned and the logging level is set to Debug for ROOT as well as the specified package. However, log.debug does not come up, log.info still does.  Also, the {debug="true"} statement was to print out whether logback is scanning the correct file and setting the levels correctly.

Comment: What did you expect to see that you aren't seeing? What debt logs? If you log nothing on debug nothing is going to be logged. To enable debug logging for spring boot start with the --debug parameter.

Comment: java $JVM_PROPS $DEBUG_PROPS -jar projectname.jar --spring.config.name=application,spring-jms,spring-amqp,persistence  --debug   : Are you referring to the parameter in the end. It is very much there.  I am talking about log.debug("abc") not getting printed... log.info("abc") is printed though

Comment: It works well when the same logback.xml config file is packaged with the jar.

Comment: So, essentially my problem is that even though the application seemingly scans the file pointed to by -Dlogback.configurationFile, it is not applied. Quite weird!

Comment: I got the external logback.xml file to work with logging.config=file:<location> but not with -Dlogback.configurationFile=<location>

Answer (score 0):

I got the external logback.xml file to work with logging.config=file: but not with -Dlogback.configurationFile=

Comment: Where did you configure it?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that the external logback.xml file is *in the classpath*. It should be picked up.

Also make sure that you do not have any file named logback-test.xml, else it gets the priority, and will be used.

Comment: There is no xml file in the packaged jar, I opened up the jar to verify that. The logback.xml is in the same dir as the application (jar). It was not picked up with/without -Dlogback.configurationFile='absolute path for logfile.xml'